# Content not from webpack is served from /foo

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I just can't start this server, I read the [webpack-dev-server docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver).

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  compress: true,
  port: 9000
}
```

The sample code looks simple,but I just can't start this server successfully,no matter what I tried,different folder,it just can't get the **content**!!!Am I missing something?

Any help would be great appreciate.

Output:

```
Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
webpack output is served from /assets/
Content not from webpack is served from ~/WebstormProjects/react_back/assets/
```

My project structure:

```
├── [drwxr-xr-x ]  src
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- ]  index.js
├── [drwxr-xr-x ]  public
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- ]  index.html
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x ]  assets
│   │   └── [-rw-r--r-- ]  bundle.js
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- ]  favicon.ico
├── [-rw-r--r-- ]  package.json
├── [-rw-r--r-- ]  npm-debug.log
├── [-rw-r--r-- ]  webpack.config.js
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval"
  },
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        filename: "assets/bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname + "/assets/",
        inline: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8080,
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2016", "react", "env", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**Version:**

```
➜  node -v
v7.6.0
➜  webpack-dev-server -v
webpack-dev-server 2.4.1
webpack 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The first problem is that you're serving the content from `assets/` but you don't have that directory, you have `public/assets/` and that's not even what you want, because your `index.html` is in `public/`. So what you really want is setting the `contentBase` to `public/`:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname + "/public/",
    inline: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080,
},
```

Now you'll still have the problem that `webpack-dev-server` doesn't serve the correct bundle. It might work, but that is because you have the bundle on your actual file system, which will be used instead of the bundle that `webpack-dev-server` would serve from memory. The reason for that is that `webpack-dev-server` only serves from memory if the correct path is hit. Assuming you're including `assets/bundle.js` in your `index.html`, that would match the path, but you're setting `publicPath: "/assets/"`, so it will be looking for `/assets/` and adds the filename to it (which is `assets/bundle.js`, in reality the bundle is served from `/assets/assets/bundle.js`.

To fix that you can either remove the `publicPath` option (setting `publicPath: "/"` has the same effect).

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public",
    filename: "assets/bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
},
```

Or you can change the output path to `/public/assets/` and the filename to just `bundle.js`. This will also make your chunks go into the assets directory, which is probably what you want anyway.

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public/assets/",
    publicPath: "/assets/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
},
```

*Note: `publicPath` affects some loaders that change the URL of assets.*

Comment: You answered my doubts,I can see the content,but why the outptu is still `webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from ~/WebstormProjects/react_back/public/`

Comment: That's the server path, it's served from `/`, that is in that case `http://0.0.0.0:8080/`. It doesn't show where the content comes from but where you can request it.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the webpack dev server `^v4.0.0` (still an RC at the time of this post), the `contentBase` property is changed to `static`.

```
devServer: {
   // ...
   static: __dirname + "/public/",
   // ...
},
```

The CHANGELOG: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#static

Comment: Yupp it's giving below error

```[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. - options has an unknown property 'contentBase'. These properties are valid: object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }```

Answer (score 3):

This might be issue with 'react-scripts', for me it was not working for 3.4.1 version, I made the version to 3.4.0 and it is working now.
Open package.json file, and change "react-scripts": "3.4.0", if it is something else, OR you can try different versions as per your requirements. But this issues seems to be with "react-scripts" version so you need to check that.

Comment: It worked for me also by changing to 3.4.0. Does anybody know the reason behind this ?

Comment: This worked for me! Can anyone shed some light as to why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved after changing the react-scripts version 3.4.1 to 3.4.0. Don't know why!

Comment: It worked for me also by changing to 3.4.0. Does anybody know the reason behind this ?