# Seeing a blank page on deploying create-react-app application to heroku

Tags: reactjs

No webpack config since I have not ejected. I'm seeing an empty root div.
This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ttt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://tictactoezz.herokuapp.com/",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my server/server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use('/static', express.static(publicPath));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log('Server is up!');
});
```

Please help! Unlike other questions posted here, I do not see any errors in the console.. just a blank screen. It works on localhost:3000

Comment: Check your Heroku error logs

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have server.js for heroku deployment if you use create-react-app. In case you insist to have server.js, it should point build folder, not public folder. You need to run `npm run build` first and then server.js should server contents on build folder. You can add a new script for `heroku-post-build`.

```
...
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
...
```

Comment: Yep, I realized that and then got this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61558585/heroku-content-not-from-webpack-is-served-from-app-public-despite-using-all-d

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your `start` script includes building the react app. Can you try this?

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same problem for two days. Express&React.js app was working fine on localhost but not on heroku. I added this to server.js and problem solved.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './frontend/build')));
```

My react.js folder had the name "frontend" and it was at the same level with my `server.js` file. And don't remove `build` name and dont change it to any other name. `build` is a default folder for your react app to launch.