# How to run Express-React project

Tags: reactjs, express, npm

I`m trying to understand how to run this project, published on GitHub [here](https://github.com/haimHadad/ReactExpressProj.git)

No idea how. I ran npm i, and then npm start, but I got these messages:

```
npm start

> fed-entry-level-exam-root@1.0.0 start C:\entry-level-exam_19\entry-level-exam
> lerna run start --parallel

lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info Executing command in 2 packages: "npm run start"
@fed-exam/client: > @fed-exam/client@1.0.0 start C:\entry-level-exam_19\entry-level-exam\client
@fed-exam/client: > set CI=true && react-scripts start
@fed-exam/server: > @fed-exam/server@1.0.0 start C:\entry-level-exam_19\entry-level-exam\server
@fed-exam/server: > ts-node-dev index.ts
@fed-exam/server: [INFO] 21:51:34 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.0 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript    ver. 3.9.9)
@fed-exam/server: starting server { serverAPIPort: 3232, APIPath: '/api/tickets' }
@fed-exam/server: server running 3232
@fed-exam/client: i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.0.108/
@fed-exam/client: i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
@fed-exam/client: i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\entry-level-exam_19\entry-level-exam\client\public
@fed-exam/client: i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
@fed-exam/client: Starting the development server...
```

I tried to open http://localhost:3232/ but I getting this error:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Also tried :
http://localhost:3000

Which is known for React localhost.

So far I don't know how to make it work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

run the client and server separately,
after running **npm install** and **npm start**
open a new terminal and run **npm start** inside **client/** directory

Comment: Are you sure? I been told to run everything through the root folder

Comment: Yes, bro.. i have checked the project, configurations are not done to run the project from the root folder, that's why the best solution is to run the client and server separately

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully read messages on the console you will notice where the api is running.

The lines

> @fed-exam/server: starting server { serverAPIPort: 3232, APIPath: '/api/tickets' }
>
> @fed-exam/server: server running 3232

Shows that server project is running at port 3232, but that api path starts at `/api/tickets`. So, for access the root of the api, access `http://localhost:3232/api/tickets`.

You could check how this works by checking the express app code on server folder.

And there is a problem with the client code that is related with react-scripts when trying to run projects using lerna package. The line

> Content not from webpack is served from C:\entry-level-exam_19\entry-level-exam\client\public

Was previously reported as error here: [Content not from webpack is served from /foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712054/content-not-from-webpack-is-served-from-foo)

Try to solve the issue using our colleagues suggestions.